# Can "for any" be rephrased as "infinetly often"

Tags: probability, probability-theory

If it is stated that an event $A(t)$, i.e. depening on $t$, happens for all $t > 0$ where $t \in \mathrm{IR}$.

Can this be rephrased as $A(t)$ happens infitely often?

Comment: No. "For all" means for all. Infinitely often means that it the set of $t$ such that $A(t)$ happens is infinite.

Comment: A simple example would be the event $A(n) = \{n \text{ is prime}\}$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$.  Then $A(n)$ happens infinitely often, but it is definitely not true that every natural number is prime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it cannot. For example, if $A(t)$ happens if and only if $t$ is an integer, then it would happen infinitely often, but it does not happen for all positive real numbers.